# what is the meaning of "Entrepreneurial entry"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, translation

I'm translating a paper from English that is in the field of entrepreneurship. I came across the term "Entrepreneurial entry" in this paper and since there is no equivalent for this term in my language, I wanted to know its exact definition; should I translate it like "entering an Entrepreneurship Opportunity in a business"? or does it have a different definition?

your help is much appreciated

Comment: You can try using the context (where the term was found) to guide you.

Comment: @Lawrence there is only one sentence about this term (which is the sentence that the term is used in) and it says: 
"Entrepreneurial entry is the opportunity for entrepreneurs to devise new products
and be innovative " do you have any suggestions based on this sentence?

Comment: That looks like a definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the abstract of some academic papers, it seems that in economics literature, "entrepreneurial entry" means not only the opportunity for people to devise new products, but the general phenomenon of people deciding to switch to self-employment, or to start their own businesses.

Some examples:
"Much of prior research recognizes that entry into entrepreneurship involves a comparison of expected economic returns in a venture to some threshold level of acceptable performance." -https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167268112002016

"Interest in the role of entrepreneurial entry in innovation raises the question of the extent to which tax policy encourages or discourages entry. We find that, while the level of the marginal tax rate has a negative effect in entrepreneurial entry, the progressivity of the tax also discourages entrepreneurship, and significantly so for some groups of households." - https://ideas.repec.org/h/nbr/nberch/10808.html

"This paper utilizes the Panel Study of Entrepreneurial Dynamics (PSED) dataset in investigating black and Hispanic entrepreneurial entry as compared to white nascent entrepreneurs around three important dimensions: motivation, business strategy, and community resources." - https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1084946712500033

From these examples, I think "entrepreneurial entry" simply means "entry into entrepreneurship".